# Ubuntu installation does not start, windows boots first

Tags: system-installation

I have a HP Pavilion dv7 multimedia laptop with a Windows Vista installation that I don't want. All I want to do is to install Ubuntu 10.04 and get rid of windows. The BIOS boot order is set for the USB pendrive first, then the DVD ROM drive, then the hard disk, but windows always boots up first instead of the ubuntu 10.04 pendrive or ISO disk. This also happens with the boot repair disk. Start-up ignores the disk drive and loads windows.

What might the problem/solution be? I am considering formatting all the hard disks on the laptop including the HP recovery disk to see if I can install ubuntu from scratch more easily but I'm worried that it might complicate what appears to be a relatively simple problem. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: What you mean by "booting the ISO"?

Comment: I try to install ubuntu 14 from the disk but windows always boots up instead of the ubuntu installation disk. This also happens with the boot repair disk. Start-up ignores the disk drive and loads windows.

Answer (score 0):

Some BIOS enable you to choose where do you want to boot instead of following a priority, a common problem is that people change the priorities and forget to save.

Another thing that is common is that the dvds are badly burned, to avoid this you should install using a USB.

Visit http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

here you can create a USB ready to use on all pcs without having to worry if the disk is ok or not.

Comment: I made a usb pendrive to install ubuntu today but windows still boots up as before. I made sure I saved the boot priorties as well but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Can you try to enable Legacy USB support on BIOS and try another flavor or ubuntu? maybe that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Can you disable booting from the HDD entirely in the BIOS (you can in mine, although it's a fairly recent Dell Inspiron Core i5 that I bought about a year ago, with a UEFI motherboard)?  If so, what happens if you do that?

Another idea is that often there is a 'boot options' menu you can go into as the PC is starting up (on mine you press F12), which allows you to choose where to boot from.  Maybe that could help?

If your system has Vista then I'm guessing it's not UEFI?

Comment: I'm afraid the computer doesn't have a UEFI board. I can't disable booting from the HDD.